# Pine - Conditional background color based on trade outcome

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

## My Goal

To color the background for the period trades are active in a color that adapts to the outcome of that particular trade. If the trade hit the stop loss, it would be colored red. If if hit the take profit, if would be colored green.

## The Code

```
TradePaint = if strategy.opentrades > 0
    color.new (color.white, 95)

TradeColorCondition = if ta.change(strategy.netprofit) > 0
    TradePaint := color.new (color.green, 80)

else if ta.change(strategy.netprofit) < 0
    TradePaint := color.new (color.red, 80)


bgcolor(TradePaint, title= "Trade Overlay")
```

## The Problem

Can't get the bgcolor function to color the whole range the trade was open for in the conditional color. Only the point where the trade closes gets colored, as can be seen in the image below...

The current state of the bgcolor background:
[image: current state of the bgcolor background]

Comment: You have a gray-ish area in the screenshot. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: I'd like that grey area to change green or red depending on that trade outcome. At this time, only the last bar of the trade does...

Comment: You cannot change color of the past bars, because `bgcolor` changes color on the bars where calculation is happening.

Comment: I see. Can you not ask it to, when considering what color to apply to bar where a trade started, to check X future bars for that trade outcome, and only then determine what color to produce?